# Bubble sort on elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I have a table that contains the theoretical rate of something (id=ratebaseX) and the actual observed rate of something (id=rateseenX). I have a javascript that runs through each pair and simple calculates the difference (id=calcX).

After this difference is calculated, I would like to do a bubble sort on the calcIDs array based on this calculated difference. I don't actually want to change the html or anything thing in the calcIDs class, just the index in the array.

For tests, I dump the first three array elements into an alert box because I know they are originally out of order.

```
function calcLikelihood(){
    ratebaseIDs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="ratebase"]');
    rateseenIDs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="rateseen"]');
    calcIDs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="calc"]');

    for(i=0;i<calcIDs.length;i++){
        likelihood = Math.round((ratebaseIDs[i].innerHTML - rateseenIDs[i].innerHTML)*100)/100;
        calcIDs[i].innerHTML = likelihood;
        calcIDs[i].likelihood = likelihood;
    }
    //bubble sort based on likelihood
    for(i=0;i<calcIDs.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<(calcIDs.length-1);j++){
            if(calcIDs[j].likelihood<calcIDs[j+1].likelihood){
                temp = calcIDs[j];
                calcIDs[j] = calcIDs[j+1];
                calcIDs[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    alert("0) " + calcIDs[0].likelihood +"\n1) " + calcIDs[1].likelihood+"\n2) " + calcIDs[2].likelihood);
}
```

The problem is that first three elements do not move. I am pretty sure I got the bubble sorting correct. I think the problem is that calcIDs is acutally an array of pointers?

Comment: To get the HTML elements themselves to move you will have to *remove* them and then *append* them back in the correct order.

Comment: Unless this is for an assignment where you specifically have to implement bubble sort, I cannot think of a worse choice of algorithm.  If you are merely after a way of sorting an array, your best choice is to use the sort() method of the Array class.

Comment: @MattBurland - `remove them and then append them` - appending them removes them from their original location, so, that's not strictly correct :D

Comment: Also not only as @JonTrauntvein said, there are better ways to sort an array rather than implementing bubble sort yourself (and potentially getting it wrong), there are also javascript libraries available that will create sortable tables for you.

Comment: Rather than using bubble sort try sort() method.....http://modernpathshala.com/Forum/Thread/Interview/7294/write-a-code-snippet-to-sort-string-array-in-jquery

Comment: More useful link for the `Array.sort` method: [Array.sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp). Other comments re DOM elements seem correct.

Comment: @Neofish: w3schools is rarely a good link. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) links are usually much better.

Comment: Could you sort the table before, via Server Side Script? Or is the data presented to only in a table, are you scraping it?

Answer (score 0):

Your bubble sort is ok, I checked it:

```js
var calcIDs = [{likelihood: 84}, {likelihood: 56}, {likelihood: 68}, {likelihood: 81}];    
    //bubble sort based on likelihood
    for(i=0;i<calcIDs.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<(calcIDs.length-1);j++){
            if(calcIDs[j].likelihood<calcIDs[j+1].likelihood){
                temp = calcIDs[j];
                calcIDs[j] = calcIDs[j+1];
                calcIDs[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

console.log("0) " + calcIDs[0].likelihood +"\n1) " + calcIDs[1].likelihood+"\n2) " + calcIDs[2].likelihood); 
// 84, 81, 68
```

So, I think the problem is that `document.querySelectorAll` doesn't return an array. It returns an object of [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) `NodeList` whereas you can normally sort only true arrays in JS. I mean you can apply a sorting algorithm to a collection, but the "sorted" items will be shown in the same predefined order as they have been shown before sorting. A simple workaround might be converting the collection of nodes into an actual array like this:

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes); // nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".your_selector");
```

and then you will be able to apply the sorting and get what you expect. It is ok for your purpose because you state you don't want to change the view. I hope this late answer helps :)